# Wikipedia API + Cross-origin requests

Tags: javascript, cors, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to access Wikipedia using JavaScript and [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing%20%29).

As far as I know, Wikipedia should support CORS: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests

I tried the following script: create a XMLHttpRequest+credential/XDomainRequest, add some HTTP headers ("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", etc.) and send the query.

http://jsfiddle.net/lindenb/Vr7RS/

```
var WikipediaCORS=
    {
        setMessage:function(msg)
        {
            var span=document.getElementById("id1");
            span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
        },
        // Create the XHR object.
        createCORSRequest:function(url)
        {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            if ("withCredentials" in xhr)
            {
                xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            }
            else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined")
            {
                xhr = new XDomainRequest();
                xhr.open(method, url);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return xhr;
        },
        init:function()
        {
            var _this = this;
            var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Javascript&format=json';
            var xhr = this.createCORSRequest(url);
            if (!xhr)
            {
                this.setMessage('CORS not supported');
                return;
            }

            xhr.onload = function()
            {
                _this.setMessage(xhr.responseText);
            };
            xhr.onerror = function()
            {
                _this.setMessage('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
            };
            xhr.send();
        }
    };
```

But my script fails ('xhr.onerror' is called). How can I fix it?

Comment: Fails how? What message do you get? Errors in the console?

Comment: the AJAX.onerror function is called "Woops, there was an error making the request."

Comment: Wikipedia has to send the CORS header, not you.

Comment: @DanFromGermany if I remove the calls to "setRequestHeader", it still fails.

Comment: You should have added the real errors, use the console log.
`Refused to set unsafe header "Origin" (index):1
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Javascript&format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. `

Comment: The accepted answer should be the one of Ashton Morgan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CORS headers are sent to *allow* a requesting script to access the contents.

Wikipedia is sending the CORS, not *you*.

**According to the comments:**

Wikipedia is an exception to general rule, by requiring you to append an `origin` parameter to the URL you are requesting.

I think the reason behind this is related to caching. I don't know what kind of mechanism they are using, but it probably makes it easier and better for them to store a cache object and build variations that way.

---

More on CORS from MediaWiki API documentation:

> The MediaWiki API also requires that the origin be supplied as a
> request parameter, appropriately named "origin", which is matched
> against the **Origin header required** by the CORS protocol. Note that
> this **header must be included in any pre-flight request**, and so should
> be included in the query string portion of the request URI even for
> POST requests.
>
> If the CORS origin check passes, **MediaWiki will include the
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true header in the response**, so
> authentication cookies may be sent.

This means you have to send an `Origin` header to tell Wikipedia where you are coming from. Wikipedia is managing the access, not you.

Send this origin header:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Origin", "http://www.yourpage.com");
```

`Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are **response** headers, not **request** headers.

Wikipedia additionally requires content type *json*:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my script http://jsfiddle.net/lindenb/Vr7RS/2/ and set the two headers: that still doesn't work.

Comment: @Pierre did you get it to work? I tried but didn't :S

Comment: no, it didn't , but as far as I understand  Ronni Skansing 's comment, en.wikipedia.org doesn't seem to allow CORS.

Comment: You could try with `JSONP` instead, or a serverside solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I used that solution before: http://lindenb.github.io/pages/pubmedwp/index.html

Comment: Note in the above: "should be included in the query string portion of the request URI". So you cannot set the header, you must add '&origin=* to the actual url.

Comment: Just spent a couple of days messing up with Apache's CORS config without realising this. Thank you so very much!

Comment: Setting the origin header doesn't work now (maybe things are different in 2019), Chrome is not happy - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182712/refused-to-set-unsafe-header-origin-when-using-xmlhttprequest-of-google-chrome. Answer by @ashton-morgan works, however (adding &origin=*).

Answer (score 128):

I had the same problem while working on a [freeCodeCamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeCodeCamp) project and the solution was so simple it made me laugh, since I had spent hours searching for it. In your jQuery URL include the parameter below.

`&origin=*`

[Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/luckyguy73/full/GqPzZO/)

```
$.getJSON(
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&gsrlimit=15&generator=search' +
  '&origin=*' + // <-- this is the magic ingredient!
  '&gsrsearch='q, function(data){ /* ... */ }
);
```

Comment: Yo, thanks! I'm working the the same project and was in a pickle in regards to CORS with the Wiki API.

For some reason when I read this:

 "The MediaWiki API also requires that the origin be supplied as a request parameter" 

I didn't realize I just had to do just as you pointed out. 

It seems kind of weird though since isn't it the site hosting the requested files that usually sets the allow header? Such as: 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin> | *

Comment: Also, could you post a link to where you found this solution?

Comment: THANK YOU! I was pulling my hair out. I was able to use the API yesterday and today I kept getting the cross origin issue. Adding this allowed my request to work again.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&origin=*&format=json&search=xxx. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:2222' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I'm also doing the fcc challenge

Comment: Not working - try this: `https://wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&origin=*&prop=extracts&list=&continue=&titles=&generator=search&callback=&formatversion=1&exsentences=3&exintro=1&explaintext=1&exsectionformat=plain&gsrsearch=javascript`

Answer (score 21):

As of August 2016, Wikipedia supports CORS requests by using the normal Ajax requests (no need of JSONP/callback manipulation).
This can be done by setting the origin in the API call.

For authenticated requests, this must match the one of the one of the "origins" in the Origin header exactly (you need to set this using the beforeSend property while making an Ajax call).

For unauthenticated requests, you can simply set it as an asterisk (*), and it works when using a simple $.getJSON from your domain.

Example API call: 
`https://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&origin=*&search=stack&limit=10`

More is at the MediaWiki API sandbox: [MediaWiki API sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&list=search&srsearch=meaning)

Comment: The example only works without origin if you do it in a browser, not if you do it with AJAX.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery JSONP:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
    jsonp: "callback", 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    data: { 
        action: "query", 
        list: "search", 
        srsearch: "javascript", 
        format: "json" 
    },
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    success: function(response) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `origin=*` alone with the URL was not working for me so added `withCredentials=false`. It will work.

Those whoever are facing issue again after adding `origin=*`: Try the below one with `withCredentials = false`

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=5&origin=*&search=simple";
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText)
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.withCredentials = false;
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xhttp.send();
```

Credits to @muraliv

Comment: Works, but you repeatedly forgot `this` for request properties. Edited.

Comment: Who is "muraliv"? What does it refer to? An answer? A comment?