# The difference between accessing the NY Times API and a Wikimedia API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss

I am currently taking the [Udacity Front-End Web Developer Nanodegree](https://www.udacity.com/course/front-end-web-developer-nanodegree--nd001) course, and I'm on the AJAX course.

My project is to take an addrress and:

- load New York Times articles
- load a background image from Google Streetview
- load relevant articles from Wikipedia

I have the first two done.  The third requires either `jsonp` or `CORS`, and my question is: **why?**

What is the difference between these first two calls that work just fine:

```
http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=somecity&api-key=...
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x400&location=...
```

and this one that fails?

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=...
```

*Note*: The above urls are:

- searched for articles using `jQuery.getJSON()` (NY Times)
- used as the `src` for background image  (Google StreetView)
- searched for relevant articles using `jQuery.ajax()`  (wikipedia)

The error message from the WikiPedia attempt is:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://...' is therefore not allowed access.
```

To reiterate:  What scenario is wikipedia trying to prevent?

**Update**:

The actual urls used are:

- `http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=somecity%20somestate&api-key=...`
- `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x400&location=999%20main%20st,%20somecity%20somestate`
- `https://en.wikipedcwodecgia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=somecity%20somestate&callback=jQuery111107555398044642061_1459988112375&_=1459988112376`

Comment: If using the Wikipedia API, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952045/wikipedia-api-cross-origin-requests

Comment: Those answers do not answer my question, which is not about *how*, but *why*.

Comment: do you want a request that doesn't fail or the explanation....

Comment: pretty sure its mostly for legacy browser support...https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests

Comment: @albert: An explanation, please.

Comment: yeah couldn't tell ya. want to say its security + legacy support, but would think that google would be applying the same security standards as well. not being condescending, but do you get why CORS/JSONP exist/are used in the first place?

Comment: @albert: Nope, that's what I'm hoping to learn.  :)

Comment: good on you....hopefully i can get back to you on this later tonight...

Comment: @albert: Any chance you can answer?  No one else is stepping up to the plate.  :(

Comment: good enough? more clarification or want/need resources? since you care, i'm happy to help

Comment: @albert:  Much appreciated.  I'm still not clear on the differences between the google and wikipedia methods... google doesn't require keys nor CORS/jsonp and yet it works just fine -- does http vs https have anything to do with it?  If there is some good tutorial out there I'm happy to go read it.

Comment: gmaps key is not in the url, i goofed that on the ?, apologies. you still have to authenticate when you sign up though. and this seems to say you have to have one. i do remember between v2 and v3 when they dropped it entirely...been using leaflet forever now so i'm out of the loop. i'll deep dive and get back to you. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% on what Wikimedia is trying to prevent here...

Same-origin policy is the root of your question, a directive from the web application security model that requires `script`s from one page (HTML document, etc.) to be of the same origin as another page, in order to access that other page's data.

Its the literal wall that keeps all the script kiddies from wreaking havoc and mayhem on websites.  Like all great walls, same-origin policy works both ways: if you have data/access/services to be consumed/used, your options are severely limited.

One option is the Google Maps/ APIs option, where you sign-up, get a key, bypass the same-origin policy via authentication.

Another option is JSONP, where the "P" is a function wrapped around the JSON data. The function's payload, the JSON, is accessible to `script`s from different origins, because its served up as an object, and enters the JS global namespace.  Invoking the function causes the browser to evaluate the return payload as JavaScript and allow it across origins.

A third option is CORS - Cross-origin Resource Sharing. It overcomes same-origin policy by checking the origin making the request against a list of preselected origins. If the origin is on the list, it is returned in the server's header response, granting access.

Again, I'm not entirely sure why Wikimedia uses JSONP and CORS to overcome same-origin policy, but allowing access between member sites has got to be a major driving force behind that.