# fetch() with the Wikipedia API results in "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Tags: javascript, fetch, wikipedia-api

```
fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json')
    .then(  
        function(response) {  
            if (response.status !== 200) {  
                console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);  
                return;  
            }

            // Examine the text in the response  
            response.json().then(function(data) {  
                console.log(data);  
            });  
        }  
    )
    .catch(function(err) {  
        document.write('Fetch Error :-S', err);  
    });
```

The fetch address I'm using is listed here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page under simple sample. Currently it catches on the error on the bottom with `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` So far I've been unable to access any data from the API after trying different things with fetch()

Any help would be appreciated!

The project is on codepen here: http://codepen.io/javascriptisscary/pen/RazKWB

Comment: If you open your console when you're running the request, you'll see the actual network error being logged by your browser. It's related to CORS, not anything particular to your code.

Comment: Try this: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/API:Cross-site_requests

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106041/does-wikipedia-api-support-cors-or-only-jsonp-available/37109743#37109743
CORS not supported by Wikipedia, use JSONP

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to `fetch()` using CORS. However, when I changed to `mode: "no-cors"` I was no longer blocked on Cross-origin request but given a status code of 0.

According to this documentation from google: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch?hl=en

" 'no-cors' is intended to make requests to other origins that do not have CORS headers and result in an opaque response, **but as stated, this isn’t possible in the window global scope at the moment.**"

So currently to access the wikipedia api, one will have to use a different way than `fetch()`

Comment: You said it was fixed: 'when I changed to mode: "no-cors" .'  How exactly did you do that to solve this?  I see nothing about "mode" in your question or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct. As to the comment on where to set the 'mode" just do this:

```
 fetch(url, { mode: 'no-cors' })
```