# Unable to fetch resource with fetch, NetworkError

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch-api

I'm fetching data from my API using this. It will post email and password to my API:

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3001/signin', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: this.state.signInEmail,
      password: this.state.signInPassword
    })
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data === 'login success') {
        this.props.onRouteChange('home');
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e))
};
```

and the request will be handled in the API by this

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.email === db.users[0].email && req.body.password === db.users[0].password) {
        res.json('login success')
    } else {
        res.json('login fail')
    }
});
```

This will result in:

> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

However, if the `.then` are removed and the `this.props.onRouteChange('home');` is added below like this

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/signin', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: this.state.signInEmail,
            password: this.state.signInPassword
        })
    })

    this.props.onRouteChange('home');
};
```

it will work and I can log in without errors.

But, the same error will still be shown if `this.props.onRouteChange('home');` is removed like this

```
onSubmitSignIn = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/signin', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: this.state.signInEmail,
            password: this.state.signInPassword
        })
    })
};
```

I've also double checked my API with Postman and the post request was successful.

This a odd problem for me and I'm new to JavaScript, please forgive me if this happens to be a careless newbie mistake.

P.S. Please let me know if more code is needed.

Comment: CORS problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333573/fetch-with-the-wikipedia-api-results-in-typeerror-networkerror-when-attempti

Comment: @evayly Unlikely. I can still log in if I put `this.props.onRouteChange('home');` below `fetch` (See code block 3), not to mention that I have cors package installed.

Comment: can you preform request in test html file without error

Comment: Yes. But only if I did it like in in code block 3.

Comment: code block 3 don't do anything and it don't catch the error if thrown

Comment: Could you suggest a way to properly catch the error?

Answer (score -1):

Are you running the app on the same client that's hosting it? Try changing localhost to your client's LAN IP and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: No changes. I ran the app on `192.168.1.1:3000` and the API on `192.168.1.1:3001`.