# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing from Wikipedia API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, axios, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to fetch data from the Wikipedia API with axios in reactJS.
This is my get request

```
axios.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=lol&format=json&callback=?')
     .then((response) => {
       console.log(response);
     })
    .catch((error)=>{
       console.log(error);

    });
```

I got this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=lol&format=json&callback=?.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Then I changed my start script to:

```
HTTPS=true yarn start
```

My server started in https but the error still persists. I have also tried changing json to jsonp as suggested in other threads but it doesn't seem to help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `origin=*` to the Wikipedia API query parameters:

```js
axios.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=opensearch&search=lol')
     .then((response) => {
       console.log(response);
     })
    .catch((error)=>{
       console.log(error);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

More details in the answer at *[Does Wikipedia API support CORS or only JSONP available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106041/does-wikipedia-api-support-cors-or-only-jsonp-available/37109743#37109743)*.