# How can I make the Wikipedia API work with Fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to use the [MediaWiki Wikipedia API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) to make simple searches to Wikipedia. For some reason, when I use the Fetch API, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```js
const text = document.getElementById('content');

fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srlimit=100&srsearch=apple')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => text.innerHTML = 'Success!')
  .catch(err => text.innerHTML = 'Failure :(');
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

When I use Chrome to go to [the link that I am making a request to](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srlimit=100&srsearch=apple), it seems to work fine. What am I doing wrong in the JS?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: For *what* reasons does it not work?

Comment: Add `origin=*` to the query parameter in the URL; see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106041/does-wikipedia-api-support-cors-or-only-jsonp-available/37109743#37109743