# jQuery not returning JSON despite getting it back via the browser

Tags: jquery, json

I can't get the following lines of code to return JSON, or even to run my simple alert() function embedded inside. I know the URL is correct, because when I paste it in the browser it returns JSON. Does anyone know what could be the problem here?

I've tried this in CodePen and JSFiddle (making sure to include jQuery) on Chrome, but no such luck.

```
$.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&format=json&callback=?inprop=url&pageids=18630637"
, function(data) {
  alert("success");
  console.log(data);          
});
```

Comment: Do you get an error message in the console?

Comment: *XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&format=json&callback=?inprop=url&pageids=18630637. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wikipedia API + Cross-origin requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952045/wikipedia-api-cross-origin-requests)

Comment: Not really a dupe. OP already used jsonp instead of json as suggested in dupe question, but was missing an `&` after the callback parameter in his querystring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a missing `&` in your querystring. Change:

```
&callback=?inprop...
```

To:

```
&callback=?&inprop...
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3063rqtb/2/)

Comment: What is this parameter?

Comment: Can you explain how/why this works?  Is it a wikipedia specific fix?

Comment: @freedomn-m the parameter is for using JSONP instead of JSON. take a look in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource) and [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916780/changing-getjson-to-jsonp) Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ah - so a duplicate - I just got a different duplicate.  Can also change to `$.ajax(jsonp: "callback",  dataType: 'jsonp', ...` which worked in jsfiddle

Comment: @freedomn-m yes but OP was using `$.getJSON` :) anyway not really dupe because he already knew that he should use a callback param, only the querystring was wrong

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Thanks that was it. I didn't even think to look for that since my browser was still returning JSON. Thank you so much. Was pulling my hair out over this one.

Comment: @Top19 Our smallest problems are the hardest to find alone :) You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving bad json because the url is wrong.
try with this url:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&format=json&callback=?&inprop=url&pageids=18630637

Answer (score 0):

Link returns invalid json according to http://jsonlint.com/

> Error: Parse error on line 1:
>   /**/inpropurl({ "b
>   ^
>   Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

```
/**/inpropurl({"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"18630637": {"pageid":18630637,"ns":0,"title":"Translation","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","pagelanguagehtmlcode":"en","pagelanguagedir":"ltr","touched":"2016-07-08T07:40:24Z","lastrevid":726282436,"length":83042}}}})
```

Comment: Are you sure it gets that far?