# Can't get info from JSON using a html form element and getJSON method using wikimedia

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to submit something to search with the form and pull info from the j son

```js
$("#target1").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.phpaction=query&format=json&prop=revisions&list=search&titles=&rvprop=content&srsearch=" + x;
  var the = function(teh) {
    $("#target2").text(teh.continue.continue);
  }
  $.getJSON(url, the);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="" id="target1">
  <input class='text-center' type='text' id='input' placeholder='Search 
    Wikipedia' required>
</form>
<div class='text-center'>
  <p id='target2'></p>
</div>
```

example link of json:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&prop=revisions&list=search&titles=&rvprop=content&srsearch=cats

I am trying to get the info from the titles but im just using the "continue" to make it shorter.
full code at http://codepen.io/nunez7890/pen/aWWXqy

Comment: Please mention the issue that you are facing.

Comment: The getJSON method is not calling the information I am asking for.

Comment: You are getting a cross origin access error

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&list=search&titles=&rvprop=content&srsearch=hello%20world. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Use ajax call with type as `JSONP`.

`$.ajax({
     url:url,
     dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
     success:the,
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     }      
});`


Let me know if this works.

Comment: Looks like its CORS issue. Refer here for solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952045/wikipedia-api-cross-origin-requests

Comment: Yes, that worked. Now I'm trying to figure how to post that your comment was the answer.

Comment: @nunez7890 I have added it as an answer. Please accept it so that other users may find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's CORS issue. Refer here for solution [Wikipedia API + Cross-origin requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952045/wikipedia-api-cross-origin-requests)

Add origin=* to the URL query params.

```
$("#target1").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&list=search&titles=&rvprop=content&srsearch=" + x;
  var the = function(teh) {
    $("#target2").text(teh.continue.continue);
  }
  $.getJSON(url, the);
});
```