# Cannot fetch data from Wikipedia API

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api, fetch-api

```
let dataObj = [];
const query = 'marvel';
fetch(`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=${query}&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&formatversion=2`)
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(data => dataObj.push(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This is the error that I receive:

> No '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to '`no-cors`' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I set the mode to `no-cors` but still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the query parameter `origin=*` to help resolve the CORS issue:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=${query}&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&formatversion=2&origin=*

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Plz don't mind me asking but,
What is origin here. Do i have to leave it  = *- or i need to get the value from somewhere

Comment: Check out this question, it desrcibes CORS and the Wikipedia API https://stackoverflow.com/q/23952045/5059657 . You effectively are setting an origin header to match any source by `origin=*`. For not authenticated requests this will be enough to get the data you need. Try it and see how it works for you.

Comment: If you were doing an authenticated request. You'd have to set the origin to match your server/client location in line with the API account you'd create. `origin=*` would be enough for your non authenticated basic data retrieval.