# Issues retrieving data from an API

Tags: api, wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Citadel_of_Qaitbay&prop=extracts&explaintext=1&exintro&exlimit=1&format=json&formatversion=2&origin=*

The extract is an empty string

Comment: This was a bug. It should be working now.

Comment: It does. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to send headers on your original request, check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23952300/4497818

Comment: The StackOverflow autolinker omitted the `*`, now fixed.