# Angular, Refused to set unsafe header "origin" when changed the header

Tags: angular

I did try to change the headers like follow

```js
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    origin: 'https://custom.url.com',
    responseType: 'text',
  }),
}

console.log('here')
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this._httpClient
    .get(
      'https://any.url.com',
      httpOptions,
    )
    .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res)
   })
})
```

But I get an `Refused to set unsafe header "origin"` from the browser.

[image]

Does somebody did fix the error?

*The reason I want to do this, is because I'm running angular in electron, and this do not send any origin...*

Comment: I don't know maybe this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182712/refused-to-set-unsafe-header-origin-when-using-xmlhttprequest-of-google-chrome/24859232

Comment: @WahabShah Kind of, But I was also wondering it because it did work for electron, but as Charles Desbiens did answered to it.

Comment: Yes exactly. What charles mentioned is the same thing in this link as well. Like its normal behavior.  Browsers forbid such thing

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: No, I think this is sadly not possible to solve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior. Manually setting the origin header is forbidden by the browser. It is a [Forbidden Header Name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) If no origin header is being added by your http client, it's because under some conditions, the origin header doesn't get added. I don't know enough to tell you which of these conditions your app is meeting, but you can read more about them on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin).

Comment: I'm also an electron user, and there I'm able to change the origin and everything works like expected, could you explain me the reason why ?  

And why does angular then do not show that we shall not set the origin ?

Comment: You can change the origin header in Electron because you can modify the user agent that is sending requests. Angular on the other hand isn't allowed to modify the user-agent. When Angular sends a request, it's sending it from your browser. For obvious reasons, websites aren't allowed to reprogram your browser's user agent.

Comment: Thx a lot, it's more clearer now. Still do not understand why angular do not provide any type validation for this one.

Comment: @Raphaël Balet Angular doesn't validate forbidden headers at run time because it doesn't need to. The browser takes care of that already.

Comment: As for giving you warnings during development, that would have to be done by the TypeScript compiler. The TypeScript compiler isn't a system for validating values though; it's a system for validating the types that values will have. There is no concept of a "NOT" type that would allow for excluding a subset of possible values that otherwise have the intended type (in this case 'string').