# How can I set a request's Origin header in the browser's Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors, xmlhttprequest

Im trying to set a origin with this code in chrome console

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('PUT', url, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Origin','https://andromeda');
```

But chrome is saying "Refused to set unsafe header "Origin""
How can i handle this error

i tried using "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
And i tried some chrome extensions

Comment: Not sure if you can, but you'd need to disable security even if it were. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/212869

Comment: `How can i handle this error` don't attempt to set unsafe headers - if the issue you have is with CORS, then deal with CORS, don't try to by-pass CORS with trickery

Comment: Duplicate of [Refused to set unsafe header "Origin" when using xmlHttpRequest of Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11182712)

Answer (score 1):

Per the Fetch standard, `Origin` falls in the category of [forbidden request-header names](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header). [Clients (scripts) are not allowed to include such headers in requests](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#headers-class); only user agents (browsers) are.

The solution to your problem is to configure [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) on the ressource your client is requesting, if you control that server. Otherwise, request the resource from the backend, not from the frontend.